# update adds then removes kernel 4.x in 18.04 LTS

Tags: updates

On consecutive updates ... my copy of Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS now running the latest 5.0.0-32 kernel will first add the latest 4.x kernel and then on the next update want to remove it. What am I doing wrong here? As I never boot the 4.x kernel should I refuse it? I've been assuming some portion of the system wanted it there for some reason, but if so, why offer to remove it next kernel update?

Comment: Please provide the output of `apt list --installed | grep linux` so we can see what kernel-related packages are installed.

Comment: Sorry that I've had no time to get back to this. As always I appreciate people taking time to tech support the clueless. I've been ignoring a problem at boot time and (duh?) I suppose this is the likely culprit or at least contributing. dbus-daemon crashing ... as there's no copy and paste with the error details I'll look for a screen capture option and post the first of it as soon as I can.